# Handling jsessionid in custom header (Tomcat 6)

Tags: java, session, tomcat, http-headers, tomcat6

**So, the problem is standard:** multiple sessions within one browser (on different tabs).

**Current solution:** sending JSESSIONID within url: `<Context cookies="false">`

**BUT** i hate showing JSESSIONID in every possible url on page and in browser bar. So, there is this crazy idea, to set it by JS in custom header for every request (our app is as a whole driven by ajax, so this is no problem).

**The question:** is there any 'trivial' solution to this? I know I can (and probably should) implement own session Manager, but maybe someone knows any existing implementations?
Or even better, some other good solution for one-window-multi-session-app?

Ps. enviroment: Java 6, Tomcat 6, Spring 3

Comment: :Try conversation scope, this [link](http://www.majureconsulting.com/Site/Home_files/conversationscope.pdf) may helpful.

Comment: This could be problematic - Spring `Conversation management support` is still in development and isn't supported by other parts of the framework. Beside core Spring, we are using MVC ans Security, so it is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather wait for Spring 3.1 Window Management:

http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-6417

I hope this will help/solve Your problem...

P.S:

Basic explanation can be found here:

http://jazoon.com/Portals/0/Content/slides/th_a3_1330-1420_kiener.pdf